# Can we access the entire hadoop job logs in a oozie workflow xml?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

## oozie #emailAction #hadoop

Im running a hadoop pig job using a oozie workflow. How Can I access the entire log for the hadoop job in the workflow xml, so that I can use it in the success/failure email action?

Thanks

**Sample Log I need in email:**

```
2016-10-26 13:58:30,385 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2016-10-26 13:58:30,480 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2016-10-26 13:58:30,522 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2016-10-26 13:58:30,522 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2016-10-26 13:58:30,608 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2016-10-26 13:58:30,639 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2016-10-26 13:58:30,640 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Using reducer estimator: org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator
2016-10-26 13:58:30,647 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator - BytesPerReducer=1000000000 maxReducers=999 totalInputFileSize=2369469310
2016-10-26 13:58:30,648 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting Parallelism to 3
2016-10-26 13:58:30,876 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - creating jar file Job5719456061273645490.jar
2016-10-26 13:58:33,816 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - jar file Job5719456061273645490.jar created
2016-10-26 13:58:33,834 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2016-10-26 13:58:33,865 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2016-10-26 13:58:33,896 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient - Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
2016-10-26 13:58:34,053 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2016-10-26 13:58:34,053 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
2016-10-26 13:58:34,115 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2016-10-26 13:58:34,166 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 18
2016-10-26 13:58:34,367 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2016-10-26 13:58:35,007 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_201610241241_0117
2016-10-26 13:58:35,007 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases A
2016-10-26 13:58:35,007 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: A[1,4] C:  R: 
2016-10-26 13:58:35,007 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - More information at: XXX/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201610241241_0117
2016-10-26 13:58:45,851 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 6% complete
2016-10-26 13:58:46,865 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 8% complete
2016-10-26 13:58:48,907 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 12% complete
2016-10-26 13:58:51,982 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 17% complete
2016-10-26 13:58:55,059 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 21% complete
2016-10-26 13:58:58,098 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 25% complete
2016-10-26 13:59:01,120 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 26% complete
2016-10-26 13:59:42,816 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 32% complete
2016-10-26 13:59:44,324 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 33% complete
2016-10-26 13:59:45,832 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 35% complete
2016-10-26 13:59:49,351 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 39% complete
2016-10-26 13:59:53,374 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 42% complete
2016-10-26 14:01:04,726 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2016-10-26 14:01:04,728 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.0.0-cdh4.7.1  0.11.0-cdh4.7.1 hadoop  2016-10-26 13:58:30 2016-10-26 14:01:04 UNKNOWN

Success!

Job Stats (time in seconds):
JobId   Maps    Reduces MaxMapTime  MinMapTIme  AvgMapTime  MedianMapTime   MaxReduceTime   MinReduceTime   AvgReduceTime   MedianReducetime    Alias   Feature Outputs
job_201610241241_0117   18  0   138 24  76  79  0   0   0   0   A   MAP_ONLY    /home/hadoop/xx/xx/xx/20161015/00,

Input(s):
Successfully read 116235853 records (2369955422 bytes) from: "/home/hadoop/xx/data/xx/20161015/00/part*"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 116235853 records (5855768014 bytes) in: "/home/hadoop/xx/xx/xx/20161015/00"

Counters:
Total records written : 116235853
Total bytes written : 5855768014
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_201610241241_0117


2016-10-26 14:01:04,747 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
```

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. What I have seen implemented is that the oozie job name is included in the mail and that people can manually find the logs with thtat.

Comment: Even when a job fails on the cluster, the oozie action is transitioned to <ok> node, leading to successful completion of the workflow. But actually it is not. So I need this logging in mail to verify the whether it is actually successful or not. Hope someone can help me here

Comment: are you using yarn?

Comment: We are using traditional hadoop mapreduce (CDH4).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question and comments I would recommend you to do the following:

Once a job fails, don't transition it directly to the OK node. Instead route it either to a fail node (if you just want to see faillures when looking on the cluster) or route it first to a mail node, and then to either OK or fail depending on your preference.

In the mail sent in the mail node, you could add the job id. Then people know that they need to look at this job on the server because something failed in it.

---

Optionally you could always send a mail, in that case use a setup with transition to either a mailOK or a mailFail node, so people know that the process ran at all, and whether they need to look at a faillure.

Comment: For a single action workflow, the above might work. But in a multi action workflow, it is not possible.

Comment: @Phani I am convinced that it is possible for any kind of workflow. If you would provide an example where it is 'impossible', I can show you how I would approach the situation.

Comment: Yeah..It is possible if we add an email action for each action in the workflow.